# Jqplot on the Iphone rendering wrong

Tags: iphone, jqplot

My pie chart is rendering pretty well (labels are smashed to the far right but it was an external script so se la vi'), however a line / bar chart of the same size as the pie seems to be getting smashed to the far right of the container just like the labels on my pie chart.

Has Anyone gotten a bar/line graph working on an Iphone using Jqplot? Im baffled and nearly burnt out :P thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So It turned out jqplot works great on the iphone, I had a funny float in the CSS that was causing a whole slew of problems including the murder of my charts, would recommend jqplot to anyone.

Comment: Hi am able to see the area,bar and pie charts perfectly in the mobile browser. But when it comes to webview its not at all displaying area graphs or pie charts instead of it it is displaying something different like line charts instead of bar charts for example.Please help me to fix the issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used jQuery Visualize, and it works pretty well so far ;-)
As I am aware, iPhone's Safari browser supports HTML5 <canvas> tag...

Get it from [here](https://github.com/em-/jquery-visualize/archives/master)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jqplot for charting on iphone, I am just wondering if you have ever implemented click action on jqplot.

For me I just tried that on any desktop browsers it works flawlessly but not when I click on series item on iphone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with iphone and ipad displaying jqplot graphs correctly but there was an issue with using an older version of jquery (upgraded to jquery 1.5.1 which solved part of the problem).